# Again over interfaces in Delphi

Tags: delphi

In order to understand interfaces I've realized a small application with a form, a data module with a simple database.
here is the form

[image]

The data module contains only a connection, a table and a TDataSource component.

The interface unit is this:

```
unit databaseInterface;

interface

uses
  MSAccess;

type
  IDBTest = interface
  ['{5B8CF4FF-66F7-402D-8E18-0159CB22F805}']
    procedure SetTable(table: TMSTable);
    function SetPriorRecord: Boolean;
    function SetNextRecord: Boolean;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

and it's implementation is this:

```
unit databaseImplementation;

interface

uses
  databaseInterface, database, MSAccess;

type
  TDBTest = class(TInterfacedObject, IDBTest)
  protected
    DBTable: TMSTable;
    FbtnPriorStatus: Boolean;
    procedure SetTable(Table: TMSTable);
    function SetPriorRecord: Boolean;
    function SetNextRecord: Boolean;
  public
    property Table: TMSTable read DBTable write SetTable;
  end;

implementation

{ TDBTest }

procedure TDBTest.SetTable(Table: TMSTable);
begin
  if DBTable <> Table then begin
    DBTable := Table;
    DBTable.Open;
  end;
end;

function TDBTest.SetPriorRecord: Boolean;
begin
  if not DBTable.Bof then begin
    DBTable.Prior;
    Result := DBTable.Bof;
  end else
    Result := True;
end;

function TDBTest.SetNextRecord: Boolean;
begin
  if not DBTable.Eof then begin
    DBTable.Next;
    Result := DBTable.Eof;
  end else
    Result := True;
end;

end.
```

Now, this is the question. The code of my form is as below:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, databaseInterface, databaseImplementation, JvExMask,
  JvToolEdit, JvMaskEdit, JvCheckedMaskEdit, JvDatePickerEdit,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Mask, Vcl.DBCtrls, JvDBDatePickerEdit, JvExControls,
  JvButton, JvTransparentButton, database;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    pnlCommands: TPanel;
    pnlData: TPanel;
    pnlMessages: TPanel;
    bvlIcons: TBevel;
    bvlNavigation: TBevel;
    lblId: TLabel;
    lblFirstName: TLabel;
    lblLastName: TLabel;
    lblBirthday: TLabel;
    edtId: TDBEdit;
    edtFirstName: TDBEdit;
    edtLastName: TDBEdit;
    dtpBirthday: TJvDBDatePickerEdit;
    btnPrior: TJvTransparentButton;
    btnNext: TJvTransparentButton;
    procedure btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    DBTest: IDBTest;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBTest := TDBTest.Create;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBTest.SetTable(dmAuthors.tblAuthors);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnPrior.Enabled := not DBTest.SetPriorRecord;
  btnNext.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnNext.Enabled := not DBTest.SetNextRecord;
  btnPrior.Enabled := True;
end;

end.
```

So I call the methods **SetPriorRecord** and **SetNextRecord** when the user click over the related button and then, accordingly with the status of the table (BOF or EOF), I disable or enable buttons.
I wonder if there is a way to set buttons status via interface, decoupling this operation from the form; for example binding buttons in any way or something else, but I don't know how to do it, if it is possible!
I hope I was clear in my explication of the problem.

Comment: _I wonder if there is a way to set buttons status via interface, decoupling this operation from the form_. It's a very easy thing to do, and there are many ways of achieving it. But I strongly advise against separating this from the form: The buttons are part of the UI, and your objective should rather be to separate your **business logic** from the UI. Think what would happen if you decided to change your buttons from JvTransparent buttons to some other kind of button. You wouldn't want your business code to be forced to change as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The existing interface is not sufficient. You need to pass in some means of letting the client know the state of the table, but without exposing the TDataSet's detailed logic (preferably). A callback to an event handler would work; a way to trigger TAction would work; as would an anonymous method. You basically need to return a flag of some kind signifying BOF, EOF, or somewhere in between; possibly also a record# and record count.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for you're answer, but I'm not expert about anonymous method so, can you please post a little example?

Comment: I could, but I suggest you stick with what you know. I rephrased the answer so it may be a little more clear. The exact callback mechanism you use is irrelevant. The point is, the client needs to know the state of the dataset in order to set the buttons. It can only know that if your interface has a way of returning it. There are four or five different ways of doing that. I suggest you try something, then if you have problems, post what you've done and ask for help. It's really not that difficult, tho.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the application interface in this way:

```
unit databaseInterface;

interface

uses
  MSAccess;

type

  IDBTest = interface
  ['{5B8CF4FF-66F7-402D-8E18-0159CB22F805}']
    procedure SetTable(table: TMSTable);
    procedure SetPriorRecord;
    procedure SetNextRecord;
    function GetIsBof: Boolean;
    function GetIsEof: Boolean;
    property IsBof: Boolean read GetIsBof;
    property IsEof: Boolean read GetIsEof;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

and this is the interface implementation:

```
unit databaseImplementation;

interface

uses
  databaseInterface, database, MSAccess;

type
  TDBTest = class(TInterfacedObject, IDBTest)
  protected
    DBTable: TMSTable;
    FIsBof: Boolean;
    FIsEof: Boolean;
    procedure SetTable(Table: TMSTable);
    procedure SetPriorRecord;
    procedure SetNextRecord;
    function GetIsBof: Boolean;
    function GetIsEof: Boolean;
    procedure SetCursorStatus;
  public
    property Table: TMSTable read DBTable write SetTable;
    property IsBof: Boolean read GetIsBof;
    property IsEof: Boolean read GetIsEof;
  end;

implementation

{ TDBTest }

procedure TDBTest.SetTable(Table: TMSTable);
begin
  if DBTable <> Table then begin
    DBTable := Table;
    DBTable.Open;
  end;
end;


procedure TDBTest.SetPriorRecord;
begin
  try
    DBTable.Prior;
  finally
    SetCursorStatus;
  end;

end;

procedure TDBTest.SetNextRecord;
begin
  try
    DBTable.Next;
  finally
    SetCursorStatus;
  end;
end;

procedure TDBTest.SetCursorStatus;
begin
  FIsBof := DBTable.Bof;
  FIsEof := DBTable.Eof;
end;

function TDBTest.GetIsBof: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FIsBof;
end;

function TDBTest.GetIsEof: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FIsEof;
end;

end.
```

So the form code become this:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Mask, Vcl.DBCtrls, JvExMask, JvToolEdit,
  JvMaskEdit, JvCheckedMaskEdit, JvDatePickerEdit, JvDBDatePickerEdit,
  JvExControls, JvButton, JvTransparentButton, database, databaseInterface,
  databaseImplementation;

type

  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    pnlCommands: TPanel;
    pnlData: TPanel;
    pnlMessages: TPanel;
    bvlIcons: TBevel;
    bvlNavigation: TBevel;
    lblId: TLabel;
    lblFirstName: TLabel;
    lblLastName: TLabel;
    lblBirthday: TLabel;
    edtId: TDBEdit;
    edtFirstName: TDBEdit;
    edtLastName: TDBEdit;
    dtpBirthday: TJvDBDatePickerEdit;
    btnPrior: TJvTransparentButton;
    btnNext: TJvTransparentButton;
    procedure btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    DBTest: IDBTest;
    procedure SetNavButtonsStatus;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBTest := TDBTest.Create;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBTest.SetTable(dmAuthors.tblAuthors);
end;


{ Begin table navigation ----------------------------------------------------- }

procedure TfrmMain.btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBTest.SetPriorRecord;
  SetNavButtonsStatus;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBTest.SetNextRecord;
  SetNavButtonsStatus;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.SetNavButtonsStatus;
begin
  btnPrior.Enabled := not DBTest.IsBof;
  btnNext.Enabled := not DBTest.IsEof
end;

{ End table navigation ------------------------------------------------------- }

end.
```

Now I think buttons are decoupled, but I'm not sure abot the solution I've found. Can It be good?

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?